# differential equation with distribution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, distribution-theory

I'm trying to solve the differential equation:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}=\delta(x)y
\end{equation}
My 'guess' was a solution of the following form:
\begin{equation}
y=A\exp\left[\int_{x_{0}}^{x}dx^{\prime}\int_{x_{0}}^{x^{\prime}}dx^{\prime\prime}\delta(x^{\prime\prime})\right]+B\exp\left[\int_{x_{0}}^{x}dx^{\prime}\delta(x^{\prime})\right]
\end{equation}
Is there any way to solve such an equation?

EDIT: more interestingly,
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}=\delta^{\prime}(x)y
\end{equation}

Comment: $\delta(x)\cdot y(x) = y(0)\cdot \delta(x)$ so the solution is $y(0) r(x) + y(0)$ where $r$ is the ramp function.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thanks Ninad. How is the equality that you wrote implies the conclusion that the solution is given by a ramp function?

Comment: Integrate both sides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we use the fact that $f\delta=f(0)\delta.$ We then get a differential equation of the form $y''=c\delta$ with condition $y(0)=c.$

The general solution to $y''=c\delta$ is
$$
y(x) = \begin{cases}
ax+b, & (x\leq 0) \\
(a+c)x+b, & (x\geq 0) \\
\end{cases}
$$

Now we only have to make $y(0)=c$ be satisfied. But this gives $b=c$ so our final general solution is
$$
y(x) = \begin{cases}
ax+c, & (x\leq 0) \\
(a+c)x+c, & (x\geq 0) \\
\end{cases}
$$
which can also be written
$$
y(x) = (ax+c) + cx H(x),
$$
where $H$ is Heaviside's step function and $a,c$ are constants.

---

A cleaner way to solve $y''=c\delta$:

Taking antiderivatives we get $y'=cH+a,$ where $a$ is some constant. Taking antiderivatives a second time gives $y=cxH+ax+b.$

Then $y(0)=c$ gives $b=c$ as before, so our solution is
$$
y(x) = cxH(x)+ax+c.
$$

---

Solving $y''=\delta'y$:

First we use that
$$
y\delta' = (y\delta)'-y'\delta = y(0)\delta'-y'(0)\delta
$$
to write the equation as
$$
y'' = y(0)\delta'-y'(0)\delta.
$$

Taking antiderivatives first gives
$$
y' = y(0)\delta-y'(0)H+a
$$
and then
$$
y = y(0)H-y'(0)xH+ax+b.
$$

Here we get a problem, though:
$$
y(0) = y(0)H(0) + b.
$$
What value does $H(0)$ have?

The only way I can see to solve this is to have $y(0)=0=b.$ Then we get
$$
y = -y'(0)xH+ax.
$$
This gives $y' = -y'(0)H+a$ and $y'(0) = -y'(0)H(0)+a$ where we have the same problem. Solving this problem in the same way as the former gives $y'(0)=0=a$ which results in the trivial final solution
$$
y(x) \equiv 0.
$$

Comment: I see that your solution works given that $x\delta(x)H(x)=0$. Is it safe to assume that? I edited my question in a way that allows me to demonstrate my intention, can you have a look?

Comment: @Yair. I think that is safe. The Dirac distribution only requires that the test function is continuous at the origin. Since $x H(x)$ satisfies that condition, it should be safe.

Comment: @Yair. To solve $y''=\delta' y$ we should be able to use a similar approach using the identity
$$y\delta' = (y\delta)'-y'\delta=y(0)\delta'-y'(0)\delta.$$
This time we will have a step discontinuity at origin.

Comment: Thanks! the problem with H(0) is exactly what I am trying to 'tackle' (this can make physics fascinating in certain situations). However, if the trivial solution is the complete solution, I shall continue to look for a better case study. My question is: can we find a second order differential equation that allows to get a 'neat' Heaviside distribution without being forced to put its coefficient to 0 for consistency (discontinuous solution)?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Ninad Munshi in the comment section, this particular differential equation can be solved with the help of the relation $y(x)\delta(x-x_0) \equiv y(x_0)\delta(x)$, because the Dirac delta will map $y(x)$ to either $y(a)$ or zero depending on whether $a$ is contained in the domain of integration of not.

Concretely, we have :
$$
y'(x) - y'(a) = \int_a^x \delta(u)y(u) \,\mathrm{d}u = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
   y(0) &\mathrm{if}\; a < 0 < x \\
   \frac{1}{2} y(0) &\mathrm{if}\; a=0 \;\mathrm{or}\; x=0 \\
   0 &\mathrm{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right\}
= y(0)(H(x)-H(a)),
$$
where $H(x)$ is the Heaviside step function $-$ which is actually to the antiderivative of the Dirac delta. Note that the middle case can use other conventions on an interval $[b,x]$. Integrating once again, we get in the end :
$$
y(x) = y(b) + (y'(a) - y(0)H(a))(x-b) + y(0)(\mathrm{ramp}(x)-\mathrm{ramp}(b)),
$$
since the ramp function $\mathrm{ramp}(x) = \max(0,x) = xH(x)$ corresponds to the antiderivative of the Heaviside function.